# Can I test my Flutter app from VSCode (Windows) on my physical iPhone device?

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

**I want to deploy my Flutter app on my physical iPhone device from my VSCode desktop application in Widnows**. I did it with React Native app in VSCode and Expo Cli on my iPhone device but I would like to do this with my Flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, you need to have Xcode which is only available on macOS in order to run the app.
You can use VirtualBox with macOS installed as a workaround but it will be very slow

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as is. You need a Mac device to develop for iOS.

There are solutions though. You could use a tool like Appollo to achieve it. Appollo is a CLI utility tool that let's you build and test iOS apps.

You can check how to use it on [github](https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo) or from their [documentation](https://appollo.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) or you can check a demo from their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBNRrJd4UP0QQRoYF4JOEmA)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's impossible to do this directly. You need to have Xcode installed to build iOS builds.
You can use cloud-based CI/CD tools to build for iOS.